# AtBeginSubsubsection | controlling the toc's font size

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

I have the folllwing `\newcommand` in order to use a reduced fontsize:

`\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{6}{5.2}\selectfont}`

So then I can call `Fontvi` througout the document to use that reduced fontsize.

For instance, I intercalate the `Fontvi` to show a reduced font size `toc` at the beginning of each section, sub-section and sub-sub-section:

```
% Outline at the beginning of every section:
\AtBeginSection[]{\label{sec:\thesection}
  \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
      \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
      \Fontvi % to make toc smaller
       \tableofcontents[
         currentsection,
         sectionstyle=show/shaded,
         subsectionstyle=shaded/shaded/shaded,
         subsubsectionstyle=shaded/shaded/shaded/shaded
         ]  
  \end{frame}
}

% Outline at the beginning of each subsection:
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
      \Fontvi % to make toc smaller
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

% Outline at the beginning of each subsubsection:
\AtBeginSubsubsection[]
{
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
      \Fontvi % to make toc smaller
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}
```

This does not seem to work for the sub-sub-section: as shown here, the sub-sub-section toc's title it's not showing up with a reduced size:

[image]

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%                                                                                                        
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
   \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[ball]
} 

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{bg=green}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\raise0.2pt\beamer@usesphere{itemize item}{bigsphere}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\raise0.2pt\beamer@usesphere{itemize subitem}{smallsphere}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[multidot]{grffile}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\newcommand{\btVFill}{\vskip0pt plus 1filll}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{section}
\usepackage{soul,xcolor}
\setstcolor{red}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.0mm,text margin right=1.0mm} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand\myheading[1]{%
  \par\bigskip
  {\Large\bfseries#1}\par\smallskip}

\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{6}{5.2}\selectfont}

\newcounter{prevsec}

% Outline at the beginning of every section:
\AtBeginSection[]{\label{sec:\thesection}
  \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
      \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
      \Fontvi % to make toc smaller
       \tableofcontents[
         currentsection,
         sectionstyle=show/shaded,
         subsectionstyle=shaded/shaded/shaded,
         subsubsectionstyle=shaded/shaded/shaded/shaded
         ]  
  \end{frame}
}

% Outline at the beginning of each subsection:
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
      \Fontvi % to make toc smaller
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

% Outline at the beginning of each subsubsection:
\AtBeginSubsubsection[]
{
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
      \Fontvi % to make toc smaller
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\title[Your Short Title]{Title}

% to Insert sectiontitle in footer:
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=3ex,dp=1.5ex,leftskip=2ex,rightskip=2ex]{page footer}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}%
            \insertsection \hfill
%       \insertshorttitle \hfill
            \insertsubsection \hfill
            \insertsubsubsection \hfill
        \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
}

\setbeamerfont{caption name}{size=\tiny}


\begin{document}

\setstcolor{red}


\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
% Uncomment these lines for an automatically generated outline.
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
    \Fontvi
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Sub-section 1.1}
\subsubsection{Sub-Sub-section 1.1.1}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\fontsize{6}{5.2}` a 6pt font written on lines 5.2pt apart? That is setting unachieivable constraints. Do not use `utf8x` with current latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm sorry, but don't follow. What would be achievable constraints otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font of the headings in the ToC can be set using  the `\setbeamerfont` command.

```
\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{size=\Fontvi}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{size=\Fontvi}
\setbeamerfont{subsubsection in toc}{size=\Fontvi}
```

[image: b]

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
                                                                                                       
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
    \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
    \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[ball]
} 

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{bg=green}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\raise0.2pt\beamer@usesphere{itemize item}{bigsphere}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\raise0.2pt\beamer@usesphere{itemize subitem}{smallsphere}}
\makeatother

\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.0mm,text margin right=1.0mm} 
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand\myheading[1]{%
    \par\bigskip
    {\Large\bfseries#1}\par\smallskip}


\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{6}{5.2}\selectfont}

%**************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{size=\Fontvi}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{size=\Fontvi}
\setbeamerfont{subsubsection in toc}{size=\Fontvi}
%**************************************************

\newcounter{prevsec}

% Outline at the beginning of every section:
\AtBeginSection[]{\label{sec:\thesection}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
%       \Fontvi % to make toc smaller % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \tableofcontents[
        currentsection,
        sectionstyle=show/shaded,
        subsectionstyle=shaded/shaded/shaded,
        subsubsectionstyle=shaded/shaded/shaded/shaded
        ]  
    \end{frame}
}

% Outline at the beginning of each subsection:
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
%       \Fontvi % to make toc smaller  % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

% Outline at the beginning of each subsubsection:
\AtBeginSubsubsection[]
{
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
%       \Fontvi % to make toc smaller % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\title[Your Short Title]{Title}

% to Insert sectiontitle in footer:
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=3ex,dp=1.5ex,leftskip=2ex,rightskip=2ex]{page footer}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}%
            \insertsection \hfill
            %       \insertshorttitle \hfill
            \insertsubsection \hfill
            \insertsubsubsection \hfill
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
}

\setbeamerfont{caption name}{size=\tiny}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    % Uncomment these lines for an automatically generated outline.
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
    %   \Fontvi % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Section 1}
    \subsection{Sub-section 1.1}
    \subsubsection{Sub-Sub-section 1.1.1}
    
    
\end{document
```